Benefit of bank groups in DDR4 and beyond
I'm trying to understand how grouping the banks together can increase the throughput of DDRx. Reading into the sense amplifier appear to be the main bottleneck in DDRx throughput, however there is already a sense amplifier in each bank, so how does grouping them together improve the latency?
Thanks

For DDR3 everything behind the I/O-gating is massively parallelized, see Micron, MT41K512M4 datasheet, and according to Gongbai Xiao, et al I/O-gating were becoming the bottleneck. Therefore in DDR4 the banks are split into bank groups with their individual I/O-gating and global I/O-gating were introduced, see Micron, MT40A2G4 datasheet. This means that in DDR4 it is still possible to maintain a continuous data stream, even for the fastest speed bins.

The Synopsys DDR4 Bank Groups in Embedded Applications Technical Bulletin explains that bank groups were introduced to avoid issues with otherwise having to increase the prefetch:

Since the core speed of the DRAM does not change significantly from generation to generation, the prefetch has increased with every DDR generation to offer increased speed at the SDRAM interface. However, continuing the trend with DDR4 would have required DDR4 to adopt a prefetch of sixteen. This change would make the DRAMs much larger because of all the wires that have to be included. It would make the DRAMs too expensive, so designers saved cost by not going to a prefetch of sixteen. More importantly, a sixteen word prefetch would not match the 64 byte cache line size common in today’s computers. With a 64 bit or 72 bit interface in a typical compute environment, which uses a 64 byte cache line, a prefetch of eight along with a burst length of eight is a better match. Any such misalignment of cache line size and burst length can have a negative impact on the performance of embedded systems.

The above Technical Bulletin doesn't mention latency explicitly, but does indicate a negative performance impact would have occurred if the amount of prefetch data exceeded the cache line size common in computers.
Also tried looking at the JEDEC standards, but:

DDR4 SDRAM JESD79-4 from September 2012 doesn't give the rationale for why bank groups were added.
The later JESD79-4D from July 2021 is only available for a fee, or to paying JEDEC members, so haven't looked at the later version.


I think the question is why splitting banks into groups increases parallelism when individual banks already have their own sense amplifiers. E.g. why can't you get the same throughput accessing two banks in the same group as two in different groups

You're correct that is the question. I the meantime, I have realized that it is column-to-column timing that should improve with the use of bank groups. However, according to Micron datasheet it seems that there is a column decoder for each bank, so I still don't understand why.

@Torben, now that you have a different accepted answer, and since my answer misunderstood the question, do you think I should delete my answer to avoid potential confusion for future readers?

@ChesterGillon, I think your answer added some insight, and your link to Synopsys' bulletin guided me i the direction of the answer I was looking for. So I think you should leave your answer. But, more experienced contributers are welcomed to give their view.
